# Portforwarded API CORS blocks requests "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I built an express API on my Raspberry Pi, portforwarded it used no-ip.com to get an adress. I am trying to use the API within my React App now, but whenever I `fetch` it, this error is thrown:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://myapi/test' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

When I try to make request to the underlying port (localhost:5000), requests are not blocked. I also already implemented `cors` into my express `server.js`:

```
const cors = require("cors");
const corsOptions = {
   origin: "*", 
   credentials:true,          
   optionSuccessStatus:200,
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

This is how I fetch it:

```
await fetch('http://converttopdf.ddns.net/test')
```

EDIT:
I figured out, that only the normal route http://converttopdf.ddns.net/ can be fetched, therefore my `default` file (forwarding):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show more code? Specifically I am wondering where exactly you do `app.use(cors(corsOptions))` relative to the rest of your routes and middleware, since it will only apply to routes you define after that.

Comment: `http://converttopdf.ddns.net/test` is returning a 404 response from nginx. The request likely isn't even reaching your JS code. The code itself looks okay but it sounds like there's a server misconfiguration elsewhere.

Comment: A request to `/test` would go to a backend route that matches `/test`. The code you showed before did not have such a route, so express would return a 404, then nginx would see it and fall into the `try_files` directive and also find nothing, and then return its own 404 page which does not have CORS headers set.

Comment: @Aurast so is there a way to automatically fetch the routes inside the default file?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. You already have nginx configured to forward all requests to port 5000. But you also configured it to `try_files` and return an nginx 404 page. If you delete the `try_files` line (and reload the configuration) then it will return the 404 response from your express server instead, which will have CORS headers.